# Javascript add variable date

Tags: javascript

This should be easy, but I'm looking to add an integer variable called "rental_period" to the current date and then display it in DD/MM/YYYY form.  This is my code:

```
    duedate.setDate(duedate.getDate()+rental_period);
  $("#pricing_due").html("DUE DATE: <strong>" +  duedate.getDay() + "/" + duedate.getMonth() + "/" + duedate.getFullYear() + "</strong>");
```

Comment: Is it the adding of the date that's the problem of the displaying?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What's not working?

Comment: My crystal ball says that your rental period is too long. May your days be nonnegative and all your months not overflowing!

Comment: @Anonymous: Mine says that `rental_period` isn't measured in milliseconds.

Comment: SLacks: Oh, I completely see how that would prevent the date from reaching 32!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript datetimes are stored in milliseconds.

Therefore, assuming that `rental_period` in a number of days, you need to write

```
 duedate.setTime(duedate.getTime() + rental_period * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

(24 hours × 60 minutes × 60 seconds × 1000 milliseconds)

**EDIT**: [Your code should work as is](http://jsbin.com/epiti).

Comment: This doesn't work, `getDate`/`setDate` work on the day number.

Comment: This works, thanks.  Any advice as to the best way to display it in DD/MM/YYYY format?  My current approach using getDay, getMonth, and getFullYear doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
duedate.setTime(duedate.getTime() + rental_period);
```

Make sure rental_period be a value in msecs (can be easily converted from whatever you have, for instance if it's in days, just multiply it by 24*60*60*1000).

**EDIT:**
For those not understanding the problem, setDate receives a day number (1 to 31), and it's behaviour (though may work on some browsers) is not defined for other values. setTime works as expected.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setDate.asp

Comment: `setDate` handles out-of-range values in every browser that I tried.

Answer (score 0):

`setDate` will only modify the day of the date object. Use something like this instead:

```
var rentalPeriod, rentedDay, dueDate;
rentalPeriod = 14 * 24 * 3600 * 1000; // in milliseconds, here: 14 days
rentedDay = new Date(); // Date object of when the thing was rented
dueDate = new Date( ( +rentedDay ) + rentalPeriod );
```